# How to make menu items with sub menu in a header stack in a row

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am trying to make a dropdown menu, it's my first time doing it and I'm experimenting with it. The problem that I'm facing is this:
[image]

As you can see, the principal menus are showing in a list. I have tried displaying them as flex and other attempts, but it seems like the header is making a limitation to them and I don't know how to put them beside each other. (Clarification: 'Notificaciones' and 'Usuario' are main menus and 'Mi Perfil' is a submenu that comes from 'Usuario' (parent))

Here is my code:

```css
* {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: roboto;
  }
  .header-text {
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px 6px 2px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header-icons {
    width: 32px;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgb(20, 33, 61);
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 6px;
    position: static;
  }
  .nav li a {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1 class="titulo-logo">Lorem</h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Notificaciones</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Usuario</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=""></a>Mi Perfil</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thank you so much in beforehand!

Comment: I see a miss-closed tag for `<li><a href=""></a>Mi Perfil</li>`

Comment: Sorry @BehRouz, I don't understand what you mean, I can't see an error as I'm a beginner... what is the error there?

Comment: You need to put `</a>` after the text you want to show as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `<li>` should have `display: inline-block` for being arranged in a row. It has nothing to do with the header.
Second, the position of the sub menu (`ul ul`) needs to be absolute within a `li` with `position: relative`.

`white-space: nowrap` will make the element not wrap when the width is larger than the parent element's width.

```css
* {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: roboto;
  }
  .header-text {
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px 6px 2px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header-icons {
    width: 32px;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgb(20, 33, 61);
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 6px;
    position: static;
  }
  .nav li a {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
  
  /* added css */
  ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap
  }
  ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:100%
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1 class="titulo-logo">Lorem</h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Notificaciones</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Usuario</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Mi Perfil</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and explanation. It worked. I have a hard time understanding ul ul expressions in CSS or ul li expressions. How should I search to learn more about them?

Comment: Sure. This is a good reference to learn about selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

`ul ul` is the 3rd in the table on this link. Check out this tutorial too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgxkYbGr2II